# Is Debit card and Credit card are different for Payment Gateway?

Tags: asp.net

The payment gateways (Anyone) Is they treat Credit card as different and debit card as different?
because I am in the middle of integrating one of payment gateway in our application and See in there documentation has separate API's for Debit Card and Credit Card.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your payment gateway is concerned a debit card and a credit card are processed the same way. This has been my experience with Authorize.net, Braintree, and Paypal.

Comment: You are right @Jeff I had same experience with Authorize.net but now I'm using CardFlex SOAP integration and it does have separate API for Debit card as well as Credit card. That's why I'm confusing little bit.

Comment: if that's the case it seems to be a pretty rare situation. I'm guessing that they seperate in their own API for reporting reasons perhaps? Either way I would simply do what the API docs say if you're stuck with this gateway. Another reason might be because this CardFlex may be acting as the merchant account and the gateway. Do they give any options as to how you can tell the difference between a debit and a credit card without making the customer explicitly say? I've never seen a customer form online that asks whether the customer is paying with debit or credit.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. It's good to talk with you. I will directly contact with CardFlex Customer Support. So they will help me on this.